# Team City artifacts how can i reference them

Tags: teamcity

I have a build config that creates an html file. I want to link uploaded images to that webpage. But when I upload the images to artifacts and then open the report the images don't show. Is this even possible with the artifact system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my issue. Check for case-sensitivity.